# where is previous Terminal sessions info stored?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, high-sierra

When My computer crashes while using Terminal, I see this kind of screen when I reopen Terminal, showing me what was previously on the Terminal screen.

Where on my hard drive is that information (the one above the grey line which reads "Restored Jan 27, 2018 at 7:07:50 PM") stored for Terminal to show after the crash?

[image: restored terminal window]

Answer (score 2):

The history files for the Bash-Terminal are located within:

> ~/.bash_sessions/

(and called *.history)

or in this file:

> ~/.bash_history

(Both of them are hidden)

You can find other log files if you open the console app.

If you are curious about the Terminal.app log see
[here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278372/how-do-os-x-terminal-sessions-persist-through-reboots).